# How to remove a class from a textbox that was changed

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASP.net:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbFirst" OnTextChanged="AddClass" runat="server" CssClass="tbStyle colorBlue" Text='<%# Eval("theFirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbLast" OnTextChanged="AddClass" runat="server" CssClass="tbStyle colorBlue" Text='<%# Eval("theLastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbAdd1" OnTextChanged="AddClass" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="tbStyle colorBlue" Text='<%# Eval("theAddress1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

CSS:

```
.colorRed
{
    color: #CC0000;
}
.colorBlue
{
    color: #0000CC;
}
```

C#:

```
public void AddClass() {
    //add the 'colorRed' class to the textbox that was changed and remove the 'colorBlue' class.
}
```

How can I remove one of the class and add a new class to the respective textbox that was changed.

Comment: The textbox is inside a repeater. I will try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JS instead of call server:

```
<asp:TextBox ... Onchange="addClass(this)"></asp:TextBox> <!-- fires after losing focus-->
<asp:TextBox ... Oninput="addClass(this)"></asp:TextBox> <!-- fires after key pressing-->
<script>
    function addClass(sender) {
          $(sender).addClass('colorRed');
    }
</script>
```

It will be faster

Comment: I was able to use that but it doesn't change as I am typing, after it loses focus it updates the color. Any way to do it real time?

Comment: The textbox begins in read only mode and I use code-behind to make it not read only. Only then can the value be changed.

Comment: If so, use it in next way - `Oninput="addClass(this)"`

Comment: There is no "oninput" for asp textbox, I am sure it will work but is that the proper way? Thanks. The textbox is also inside an UpdatePanel.

Comment: oninput interpreted as member of Attributes collection and added at html markup as is. For this case it better to use javascript function because this is manipulation with markup and there is no need to make a request to the server

Comment: The only issue is, I lose the `colorRed` class on partial postback since it is inside an update panel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343938/how-to-keep-the-class-of-a-asp-textbox-on-partial-postback Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need to specify a valid Signature for the OnTextChanged event handler.

See below.

```
 protected void AddClass(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           ((TextBox)sender).CssClass = "tbStyle colorRed";
        }
```

We changed the value of the CssClass