# How to keep the class of a ASP textbox on partial postback

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net

I was hoping the JQuery script will ensure any textbox which isn't readonly will apply update to the class but that is not happening and also the `alert` isn't even being displayed. I am thinking it is because the textboxes are inside an updatepanel?

How can I keep the state of the textbox so if it had the `colorRed` class, it remains with that after a partial postback.

Comment: I guess I should  move the "readonly" removal to javascript as well?

Comment: You can change the CssClass in the server instead of using JS;

Comment: `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`  Just call your changeClass js function using scriptmanager after your update statemnt http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32392/Adding-JavaScript-and-CSS-during-an-AJAX-Partial-P

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the CssClass in the server instead of using JS;
You can also change the logic to watch the parent element and change the class of each textbox.. according with the *ReadOnly* attribute, for example. 
`$(document).on("change", "#upPerson", function(){
    $("input[readonly=true]").removeClass("colorBlue").addClass("colorRed");
});`
I did not test anything, but that's the logic.

Comment: I see what you are doing there, I can check during document.ready() to see which textbox is NOT read only and update the class... Let me test it out. Thanks.

Comment: Updated my question to help better understand my issue.